# Conexão HTML e SQL

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Estou projetando uma base de dados com onde tenho uma tabela com índices calculados de dados de outras tabelas. Estou projetando também uma dashboard em HTML para expor esses índices. Minha base de dados está armazenada em um servidor MySQL. Como eu faço para extrair esses dados e expor na dashboard fazendo o link entre as duas tecnologias?

Comment: Você vai precisar de alguma linguagem de programação para fazer isso. Acredito que é mais simples e a que mais se adéqua para você é o [tag:php].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como já falaram do **PHP** vou dar um exemplo mínimo usando **PHP** + **Mysql**.

Usando **PHP** você deveria criar um arquivo `.php` e definir nele sua conexão com o banco de dados.

Ex:

```
<?php
define("HOST", "nomedohost");    #Para o host com o qual você quer se conectar.
define("USER", "nomedousuario");          #O nome de usuário para o banco de dados. 
define("PASSWORD", "senha");           #A senha do banco de dados. 
define("DATABASE", "bancodedados");       #O nome do banco de dados. 
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
?>
```

E então chamar ele quando precisar se conectar ao banco de dados.

Para usar um arquivo **PHP**, o arquivo que você vai chamar deve ser `.php` Ex: `index.php`

E nele você deve fazer a requisição do seu arquivo `.php` com o banco de dados, vamos imaginar que aquele arquivo que você criou se chama `db.php`.

Como eu vi que você já conhece `SQL`, vou dar um exemplo usando o `Mysql`.

**Vamos imaginar que sua tabela é assim:**

```
Nome da tabela: users
Colunas: username, profile
username: Foo
profile: é um cara legal.
```

---

**Arquivo PHP com seu HTML**

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');
    $username = "Foo";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"; #sua query sql, um exemplo o SELECT *
    $query_exec = $mysqli->query($sql); #Executa o comando select.
    $row = $query_exec->num_rows; #Número de resultados encontrados.
    $get = $query_exec->fetch_array(); #Cria um vetor associativo com os dados.
    if($row > 0) {
        #encontrou resultados.
        $usuario = $get['username']; 
        $perfil = $get['profile'];
        echo "{$usuario} {$perfil}"; #Pode fazer um echo de um html, ex: echo '<div id="profile">'.$perfil.'</div>';
        #O resultado do echo seria: Foo é um cara legal.

    } else {
        #não encontrou nada.    
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <!--Colocando as tags PHP para exibir o echo no HTML-->
    <div id="username"> <?php echo $usuario; ?> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Existem muitas formas de você manipular o `echo` do **PHP**, pode fazer usando **AJAX**, **AJAX+Json**, a linguagem web acaba sendo muito extensa, mas como você precisa aprender a usar o banco de dados, você pode começar fazendo algum curso de PHP, e caso não tenha conhecimento nenhum em programação, faça um curso de lógica de programação.

Answer (score 5):

Você não vai conseguir fazer essa conexão com html. Para fazer isso você precisará de uma linguagem de programação que suporte essa conexão.

Comment: E como seria esse link do PHP com HTML?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo

Comment: Ok! Já tenho um conhecimento elementar de algumas linguagens front-end and back-end, mas estou me aprimorando! Uma das que eu não havia tido contado era a PHP, mas já comecei a dar uma olhada! Muito obrigado!